# Recursive Linear Search....help me find mistakes

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a class with a recursive Linear search method. This is what I have so far. Can you please help me out with figuring where I'm going wrong? Please :)

I was asked specifically for a method `public int linearSearchRecursive(Tile value)` and method `addTile(Tile tile)` since the parameter is `Tile` value. I do not know how to do that. Please point me in the right diretion with the tile.

```
class LinearSearch {
    public static int LinearSearch(int a[], int value) {
        return LinearSearch(value);
    }
    private int[] numbers;

    public int LinearSearch(int size) {
        numbers = new int[size];
    }


    public int linearSearchRecursive(Tile value) {

        if (value == numbers[startingIndex]) {
            return startingIndex;
        }

        else if (startingIndex + 1 < numbers.length) {
            return linearSearch(value, startingIndex + 1);
        }

        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tips :

- For your method to be considered recursive, it must call itself.  You aren't doing that right now.  You may think you are but you should look a bit closer at your method declarations.
- You should probably name your search method so that it's not easily confused with the constructor.
- Your recursive method needs a base case so it can terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Your code  is not compiled, i think you want to write  your code in some kind of pseudo code.

Firstly , i recommend you to read   Recursive Algorithm Section of  a data structure book,which is depend on your choise.

You know the complexity of Linear Search is O(n), because your list could be unsorted  and for this reason you should  look every item of this list.

```
int linearSearchIterative(int[] input, int key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i] == key) {
                return i;
            }
            else continue;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

As simple linear  search algorithms  is like above code section.

How can we  transform this algorithm from iterative to recursive? You should focus on and  resolve  this problem firstly.

When i looked your code there are  small mistakes. These mistakes

1. type of using constructor
2. recreation of int array (this array is the array in which you search the given item, so it has  no sense)
3. i cant work out the  relationship between LinearSearch constructure like method  and
   linearSearchRecursive.

When we dont  think your code stucture we can see  that your code works with error depends on logical mistake.
You firstly  control the index  parameter, if index ==  size  of array  you should return -1;
after so- called  control, you should  check  whether the item in given index is equal the key or  not.
if it is not equal call your  recursive function again.

so algorithm is like this piece of code

```
private int linearSearchRecursive(int[] input, int key,int index) {
        if (index == input.length-1) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (input[index] == key) {
            return index;
        }
        else 
        return linearSearchRecursive(input,key,++index);
    }
```